# How to convert a multi-layer JSON String to CSV in Apex

Tags: csv, apex, salesforce-service-cloud

I have a JSON string with multiple layers that I need to convert to CSV. I already have that JSON deserialized into inner classes.

JSON Structure Example:

```
{  
   "Layer1":{  
       "Layer2":{"value"},
       "Layer2":{  
         "Layer3":{  
            "Layer4":"value",
            "Layer4":"value"
         },
         "Layer3":"value",
         "Layer3":"value",
         "Layer3":"value",
         "Layer3":"value",
         "Layer3":"value",
         "Layer3":"value"
      },
      "Layer2":"value",
      "Layer2":"value"
    }
}
```

I need all "Layers" as Keys: as the CSV headers and their corresponding values

Comment: Expected csv sample for the above?

Comment: This example is for a single column in the CSV
Layer1/Layer2/Layer3/Layer4

value